# Offer discount if user shares my app

Tags: android, google-plus

I have an app on the play store, and it has an in app purchase for premium features.
I would like to offer a discount for my users if they share my app on G+ publicly.

So a user would share the play store link of my app, and he'd have to paste the post link inside my app.
Ideally i would like to have a share button inside my app, and get the link automatically to it after it gets shared.

How can i check what content the user shared (if it's the play store link) if it's a post shared by him, and if it's shared publicly?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google+ buttons policy](https://developers.google.com/+/web/buttons-policy):

"Publishers may not promote prizes, monies, or monetary equivalents in exchange for Google+ button clicks."

You probably should not be incentivizing users to perform shares.